# HTML5 video and image integration using canvas?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I have got my video & its playing fine, but now i need to add a logo on my video tag at right bottom corner(the coordinates(2,2,60,60) icon size is 60*60),
I thought of using canvas, but came up some thing like this..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testpage</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
var element = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
if (!element || !element.getContext) {
  return;
}

  var context = element.getContext('2d');
  if (!context || !context.drawImage) {
  return;
}

var google_img = new Image();
google_img.addEventListener('load', function () {
   context.drawImage(this, 2, 2, 60, 60);
},false);
google_img.src = "logo.png";

},false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center" style="padding-top:25px;">
<video src="Simplevideo.mp4"  width="610" height="380" type="video/mp4" controls="controls"><p>Your browser does not support the video.</p></video> 
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="62" height="62">Your browser does not support HTML5 Canvas element.</canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

any help to get it..

thanks in advance

shameer ali shaik

Comment: why canvas at all? Place a div containing the image over...

Comment: i need the Image(icon) as a logo on the video player, and it should be placed at the bottom corner of the video player... any sample code will be gud..

Comment: What is not working at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use a div as loxxy said in a comment, but if you really want to use canvas for some reason here is a jsfiddle with your code (fixed) :

http://jsfiddle.net/aS9VG/

The trick is to set the element to an absolute position so it can overlap another element :

```
style="position:absolute;right:150px;bottom:300px"
```